# AttributeError: 'stud' object has no attribute 'number_of_students'

Tags: python

```
class stud:

    def __init__(self) :
        try:    
            self.number_of_students = int(input("Enter number of students :\n"))
        except ValueError:
                print("Enter numerical value")
        finally:
                print(self.number_of_students)



obj1=stud()
```

when i input numerical value , its working correct

but when i gives value other than number it show eeor message that i printed in except statement but with it its also shoowing this

```
AttributeError :
  File "e:\Data\Programming\Python!!!\OOP\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 14, in <module>
    obj1=stud()
         ^^^^^^
  File "e:\Data\Programming\Python!!!\OOP\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 9, in __init__
    print(self.number_of_students)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'stud' object has no attribute 'number_of_students'
```

as i told above its showing AttributeError which i wasnt expecting

Comment: If they enter a non-number, you don't have any code that asks them to enter it again...

Comment: `self.number_of_students = int(input("Enter number of students :\n"))` If that line of code raises an exception, then the assignment **never actually happens**, and `self.number_of_students` remains undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The line `self.number_of_students = int(input("Enter number of students :\n"))` Only sets the attribute **`number_of_students`** when the input is actually a number.  When a string is entered, the code skips to the `except` clause, then to `finally` where you try to print `self.number_of_students`.

Since the value never gets set in the case of a string input, it raises an AttributeError.

If you want to print the string input, you need to set it in your `except`:

```
class Stud:
    def __init__(self) :
        input_value = input("Enter number of students :\n")
        try:    
            self.number_of_students = int(input_value)
        except ValueError:
                self.number_of_students = input_value
                print("Enter numerical value")
        finally:
                print(self.number_of_students)
```

I suspect setting `number_of_students` to a string input will break your code at some point, so it might be better to re-raise the ValueError instead:

```
class Stud:
    def __init__(self) :
        input_value = input("Enter number of students :\n")
        try:    
            self.number_of_students = int(input_value)
        except ValueError:
                msg = f"The input must be an integer, but got '{input_value}' instead"
                raise ValueError(msg)
```

Lastly, your lowercase class name `stud` is triggering my OCD, please capitalize your class names ;)

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**:

Define a class variable for number_of_students.

```
class stud():
    
    number_of_students = None
    
    def __init__(self) :
        try:    
            self.number_of_students = int(input("Enter number of students :\n"))
        except ValueError:
                print("Enter numerical value")
        finally:
                print(self.number_of_students)
```